# Minimum no of colors needed to color a rectangular area with unit cells so that adjacent cells do not have the same color(with wrapping)?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Given a rectangular m x n plane with unit cells(total m.n cells), what is the minimum no. of colors required to fill the cells so that no two adjacent cells have the same color?
In the normal case(no wrapping) 4 colors would be needed. But say the rectangular plane can be wrapped around to form a cylinder along two of its edges, then, cell at the corner is considered adjacent to the cells at the other two nearest corner cells(which leaves the cell at the  diagonally opposite corner) and the cell at the edge is adjacent to the cell on the opposite edge. Is the 4 color theorem still be valid or do we need more colors?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem#Generalizations

Comment: @DanielRust: I see that in my case i will require 7 colors. But in what pattern should i fill the colors?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following.

The question is unclear for me.

At first which cells are considered to be adjacent for the planar case: having a common edge (1) or a common vertex (2)?  In the first case two colors are sufficient:

```
121212...
212121...
121212...
```

In the second case four colors are sufficient:

```
121212...
343434...
121212...
```

but the colored graph is not plane (and hence Four color theorem is not directly applicable to it).

Now, when we wrap the rectangle to the cylinder. If the wrapped side is even, we do not need additional colors in both cases:

```
...121212...
...212121...
...121212...

...121212...
...343434...
...121212...
```

If the wrapped side is odd, we may need one additional color:

```
...1212312...
...2123121...
...1212312...

...1212512...
...3435434...
...1212512...
```

And maybe when we wrap the rectangle to the torus, we can modify its coloring, similarly as we did it for the cylinder case.